# baseboard asset tag on windows smbios

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, kvm, bios, wmic

I am trying to retrieve the asset tag which is set through `libvirt xml` on a KVM based windows VM using `wmic`. I have tried all possibilities but could not find a way to get the baseboard asset tag. I have researched and figured a utility online called `dmidecode for windows`.
Here is the snippet from libvirt xml

```
  <sysinfo type='smbios'>
    <baseBoard>
      <entry name='asset'>45af54c9-e9d9-9dc1-b999-956c76548999</entry>
    </baseBoard>
  </sysinfo>
```

Is there a way I can retrieve the `asset tag` of `baseboard` using wmic tool or any other tool (other than dmidecode)
This is what I got so far with but the tag is defaulted to `Base Board`

````
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_BaseBoard -Property *
Status                  : OK
Name                    : Base Board
PoweredOn               : True
Caption                 : Base Board
Description             : Base Board
InstallDate             :
CreationClassName       : Win32_BaseBoard
Manufacturer            :
Model                   :
OtherIdentifyingInfo    :
PartNumber              :
SerialNumber            :
SKU                     :
Tag                     : Base Board
Version                 : pc-i440fx-4.2
Depth                   :
Height                  :
HotSwappable            : False
Removable               : False
Replaceable             : False
Weight                  :
Width                   :
HostingBoard            : True
RequirementsDescription :
RequiresDaughterBoard   : False
SlotLayout              :
SpecialRequirements     :
ConfigOptions           :
Product                 : Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
PSComputerName          :
CimClass                : root/cimv2:Win32_BaseBoard
CimInstanceProperties   : {Caption, Description, InstallDate, Name...}
CimSystemProperties     : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties```
````

Comment: Like `wmic bios get serialnumber`?

Comment: similar to that, but my interest is the asset tag on baseboard.

Comment: That's why I asked... That command returns the asset tag for my old Dell, but your system might be different... Maybe what Dell calls an "asset tag" is different. `wmic baseboard` gives some information as well.

Comment: if I use the dmidecode tool from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/dmidecode.htm on windows, I get exactly what I am looking for against Asset Tag of Baseboard. But I have constraints around using such a tool.

Comment: Is this a windows guest running inside a linux host? Also, is this just to verify in windows that the asset tag was set in the VM? ... or to what end?

Comment: yes, it is windows guest on linux. It is not just to verify, but I want to derive some script based on that value.@rfmodulator

Comment: You didn't say if `wmic baseboard` shows the value (even if in a table with other values...). You might also try `wmic systemenclosure get SMBIOSAssetTag` ...but that's a different smbios type (which could be set as well).

Comment: apologies for the bad formatting ```wmic systemenclosure get SMBIOSAssetTag``` returns the asset element under <chassis>. 
```PS C:\> wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version,serialnumber
Manufacturer  Product                            SerialNumber  Version
             Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)                pc-i440fx-4.2
PS C:\> wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version,serialnumber,tag
Manufacturer  Product                            SerialNumber  Tag         Version
              Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)                Base Board  pc-i440fx-4.2```

Comment: `wmic baseboard get Tag` ...now I'm just throwing stuff at the wall to see if anything sticks. (Nevermind, looks like you tried that.)

Comment: One more idea for you to try... does the top level "System Summary" output of `msinfo32.exe` include the value you're looking for anywhere?

Comment: no, it didnt show up in system information